# jQuery - When trying to parse XML, Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: [object Document]

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have some jQuery with an Ajax call that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/photobank.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        xmlParser(xml, "Charlie");
    }
});

function xmlParser(xml, landOwner) {

    //Initial photos do not load if following line is used.
    //xml = $.parseXML(xml);

    $('#photo_container').empty();
    console.log('1');
    $(xml).find('Landowner').each(function(){
        console.log('2');
        var landownerName = $(this).attr('Name');
        if (landownerName === landOwner) {
            $(this).find('Photo').each(function(){
                $("#photo_container").append('<div class="photo ' + $(this).find("Category").text().toLowerCase() + '"><p>' + $(this).find("Animal").text() + '</p>'+ '<img class="photobank" src="images/' + $(this).find("Image").text() + '" />' + '</div>');
            })
        }
    });
}
```

You can see the XML file here: http://lamanai.org/catmap/xml/photobank.xml

However, the Ajax does not display the parsed XML, and throws this error in Chrome's console: `Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: [object Document]`. Am I calling the Ajax at the wrong time? Right now it is on document ready, since I need the initial "Charlie" category parsed on the initial page load.

If I remove the `xml = $.parseXML(xml);` line, the initial parsed XML does load, but then I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: xml is not defined` errors when trying to use the `xmlParser` function afterwards.

Any hints? This is my first encounter with Ajax.

HTML: http://lamanai.org/catmap/

JS: http://lamanai.org/catmap/js/cameramap.js

XML: http://lamanai.org/catmap/xml/photobank.xml

--

Update: The `xml = $.parseXML(xml);` line was removed, but now I'm having trouble re-using the function. The following code results in `xml is not defined` errors.

```
$('#btn_arnoldo').click(function(){
    xmlParser(xml, "Arnoldo");
});
```

I can use the following Ajax call instead, and have it work, but is it really necessary to do the Ajax each time I want to switch what part of the XML I want to use? I thought the initial Ajax gives me an object that I can parse from?

```
$('#btn_arnoldo').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/photobank.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            xmlParser(xml, "Arnoldo");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like it is already parsed.  Your xml object seems to contain an xml document already, while [parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) is supposed to be used to convert an XML string to an XML document.  If you want to access all the Image tags, you should be able to use jQuery to iterate all of them using each.

Comment: I removed the `xml = $.parseXML(xml);` line, and initial photos do load. But now I cannot use the `xmlParser` function after the first call because `xml` is undefined. http://lamanai.org/catmap/ (Hit the "Arnoldo" button to try to see another category of images.) Not sure how to define `xml` without breaking the initial call.

Comment: When I just took a look at it everything seemed to be working.  If xml isn't defined, it isn't because of anything in the xmlParser function, but where that function is being called.

Comment: Do I have to make new Ajax calls each time I want to show a different category (`landowner`)? I can make it work that way, but I thought I would just be able to clear the div and parse the XML Object again.

Comment: Ah, I missed your previous comment. My original code where xml was undefined was: `$('#btn_arnoldo').click(function(){
 xmlParser(xml, "Arnoldo");
});` Shouldn't xml have been defined since it was after the inital Ajax call?

Comment: Your variable `xml` was defined in `success: function(xml){ xmlParser(xml, "Charlie"); }`.  Unless you assign it to a variable somewhere, it will not be accessible anywhere else.  If you store `xml` somewhere accessible inside the rest of your code (global works but is bad practice), then it should work fine.  Another option is to only load the xml you need, when you need it preventing you from having to store it.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I think I understand the xml issue now, but I will definitely do some more jQuery studying.